# Sorting is getting distorted when appending dictionary to a list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sorting, data-structures

```
co_details_sorted = sorted(co_details.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["projects_count"], reverse=True)
           
s_details["co_details"] = [{k: v for k, v in co_details_sorted}]
```

my first variable is getting sorted properly, but when I am printing s_details["co_details"] it is not able to maintain the sorting logic above on the basis of projects_count.

How can I achieve it if I want the result strictly in this format [{k: v for k, v in co_details_sorted}]. I am not able to figure out

Comment: FYI, if you want to convert a list of tuples into a dictionary, just use `dict(co_details_sorted)` you don't need the dictionary comprehension.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Before 3.7, Python didn't maintain dictionary order, you had to use `OrderedDict`.

Comment: I am using python 3.9 and I have tried both the above solutions and my sorting is still getting impacted.

Comment: In that case it should work. Please post a [mre] with the value of `co_details`.

Comment: How are oyu displaying the data. E.g. `pprint` will order by key and not represent the data in its actual order.

Comment: this part of code is inside a for loop, I print it later once I have appended it into an output variable